# How can I add a new search engine to Safari without any 3rd party add-ons?

Tags: macos, safari, search-engine

I know add-ons such as Glims can do this, but I would rather stay away from them.  Any native (or more likely semi-native) way to do so?  If it matters, the engine I would like to add is [duckduckgo](http://duckduckgo.com). - Note DuckDuckGo is now in the list but was not when originally asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Safari Extension [anysearch](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/extensions/#anysearch) allows you to change the search engine used by the Safari search bar/unibar, without any hack-ish stuff such as changing the hosts file.

Comment: Here is a [direct link to AnySearch](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.matt-swain.anysearch-6M853ET88Q). Despite being an extension, it "does not have permission to read or transmit content from any webpages" according to Safari.

Comment: This was good, but Safari no longer supports search extensions:  there is this message in that AnySearch link since Jan 2020: "DEPRECATED: Safari no longer supports extensions that modify the behaviour of the address bar. "

Comment: @Martin xSearch is a new extension that works on current Safari.

Answer (score 4):

No, the only options as of Safari v 17 are Google, DuckDuckGo, Bing, Ecosia, and Yahoo. (list changes over time)

In 2012 it was just Google, Bing, and Yahoo

If it is of any help, DuckDuckGo have their own extension on the [Apple website](http://extensions.apple.com/) for Safari extensions.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame that such a thing is not configurable without extensions.

Comment: In one of the recent updates (much more recent than the question), Apple added DuckDuckGo as a search engine.

Answer (score 2):

MacHints just did a [post](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120117065228274) on this. The basic premise is that you redirect Yahoo! Search via the hosts file to the search engine of your choice.  It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

in your /etc/hosts file, add this line:

```
184.72.115.86 search.yahoo.com
```

then choose Yahoo as your default search.

Answer (score 0):

For DuckDuck&Go, close Safari, and open the Terminal and enter:

defaults write com.apple.Safari SearchProviderIdentifier "com.duckduckgo"

Answer (score -1):

This works with Safari 5.1.10 on Mac OS 10.6.8

To get Safari to open with duckduckgo (or any other) as search engine with no add ons or hacking type >https://duckduckgo.com/< (without the ><) into the Safari Preferences "Homepage" then set "New windows open with" to "Homepage" and "New tabs open with" "Homepage". This keeps the 3 default search engines as they were, at the top. OR just make the search engine of your choice a bookmark in the Bookmark bar and just click it/them.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't actually add it as a search engine, just changes what page windows/tabs open with.